# Why does the iPhone calling screen have letters under the numbers?

Tags: usability, iphone

The iPhone dialer has letters below the numbers. Why did Apple include them on this screen? In other phones it is used for T9 keyboard or contact search.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1gHH.png]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Some phone numbers are tailored to use a mnemonic "lettered" version to be more easily remembered.
Think of an insurance company running a commercial on TV and its goal is that you call their number.
If they use 1-800-**INSUR-ME**, it'll probably be more easily remembered than 1-800-**4678763**.

Comment: So, what's your mnemonic for [this](http://youtu.be/ab8GtuPdrUQ)?

Comment: There's a name for this keyboard layout, too, which is [E.161](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.161). The layout originated in American telephones for telephone exchange names during the 1930s.

Comment: @Iszi The mnemonic is the song, duh. Oh one one eight, nine nine nine. Eight eight one nine nine. Nine oneonenine, seven two five...... three.